# Elayne, Nynaeve and Egwene: do these girls ever become truly awesome as the series progresses?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

I'm reading the third book now.  I like the series but I can't help but not be too impressed with these 3. They seem to have a lot of confidence but all they seem to do in these books is be captured. Sometimes many times. Only Moraine seems to be a strong female character.

Do the books develop these characters into something more? I love how Mat, Rand and Perrin have developed so far but I'm still not too impressed with the female characters.

They display a lot of potential but mostly they just get caught by the bad guys all the time.

I hope to get to some cool stuff being done by these girls. I plan to read more of the series. So I'm just looking for yes or no answers with just a bit of spoiler free discussion.

Comment: The key thing to remember here is that those 3 are all teenagers.  They do lots of teenager things.  Moraine is substantially older.  Nynaeve developers quite a bit in some of the later books.  Egwene does too, although many people always find her frustratingly stubborn.  Elayne...well, she isn't the most popular character.

Comment: Hmmm may be them being teenagers explains it a bit. But the 3 boys are teenagers too and their characters have so many cool things going for them.

Comment: voting to close as opinion based because basic plot and character details can be easily researched on other sites better suited to that task. Asking "does somebody become awesome" or "do cool stuff" {cooler than what? by what definition?} - is purely subjective

Comment: Cool. Should I delete the question?

Comment: Might be worth noting that the way Robert Jordan writes women has gotten a fair amount of criticism.  He seemed to fall deep into a few tropes with his writing.

Comment: Interesting. I have felt that in these 3 books. So much so that I feel like switching to another series with a little more nuance. Still doing research on which one...

Comment: @RanjithRamachandra I've really enjoyed everything from the Stormlight Archive that has been released so far.  It has some WoT vibes; but just feels more focused to me.  It also ties into a larger world the author has connecting multiple series, so it can lead to quite a bit of material already if you keep reading into it.  (It's by Brandon Sanderson, who is actually the same author Robert Jordan's wife chose to finish WoT after he passed away)

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking of Brandon Sanderson as my next author. Will give it a go

Comment: If it’s not too late, I’d say stick it out. While it has its warts, Wheel of Time remains one of my favorite series, and generally does get better as it progresses (notable exception being that around book 10 it hits some drag points). Worth staying for the last three books, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Do these books develop these characters into something more.

Yes - but like all of Jordan's characters, they gain new flaws and quirks just as the overcome the old ones; the evolution of his characters usually expresses over-compensation for their previous issues. That's usually interleaved with them getting more powerful in terms of skills or the One Power.

*Rand is too soft and woolheaded to start out with? Why, he'll become harder than you thought possible!  Oh, is he too hard now? ...*

So with all the characters, as they mature and gain more powers, they'll continue to do stupid things.